# What is the right sentence ,'play on the ground' or 'play in the ground'?

Tags: prepositions

What is the right phrase?
1. I play **on** the ground.
2. I play **in** the ground.

If you pick any of these sentences, what is the reason?

Comment: Maybe you meant "I play on the playground". I'd choose the preposition "on".

Comment: Same question **[discussed on Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/preposition-in-on-at-the-field-playground.1166638/)**

Answer (score 3):

> I play **on** the ground

is the correct phrase to use since you are playing **on the surface** of the ground and the ground is not surrounding you

> I play **in** the ground

would mean you are **covered** by dirt and tunnelling or possibly digging **into** the dirt

**Ground** and **grounds** should not be confused. **Grounds** are the area around a building or an area of land which has common ownership in which case either **in** or **on** are possible

> The pond is located **in the grounds** of the stately mansion.
>   **On the grounds** behind the castle they have hunting.

Comment: But I doubt people say "I play *in* the ground." in your context. That would probably be "I play in the *dirt/sand/mud (etc)."*